# How do I control the TimeZone of events returned by the .NET Google Calendar API?

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I have the following code for use in my asp.net website:

```
CalendarService service = new CalendarService("mycalendar");
EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri(group.GroupEventsURL);
query.SingleEvents = true;
query.SortOrder = CalendarSortOrder.ascending;
query.ExtraParameters = "orderby=starttime";
query.NumberToRetrieve = 50;
query.TimeZone = "America/Chicago";
EventFeed feed = service.Query(query);
```

Which produces the following URL:

`http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/TRIMMEDgroup.calendar.google.com/private-TRIMMED/full?max-results=50&orderby=starttime&ctz=America%2FChicago&sortorder=ascending&singleevents=true`

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters) (emphasis mine), I expect the Times in each EventEntry to be in the Central time zone:

> ctz: The current timezone. If not specified, times are returned in the calendar time zone.
>
> - **Times in the resulting feed will be represented in this timezone**.
> - Replace all spaces with underscores (e.g. "ctz=America/Los_Angeles").

But my server is hosted in Arizona, so (for now) all of the dates on the calendar are two hours earlier than they should be. Am I doing something wrong? How do I get the dates in the feed to be in the Central time zone even though the server is in Arizona?

I do not plan on moving my hosting any time soon, but since Arizona does not participate in Daylight Savings Time, I cannot simply add two hours to every date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still open to other ideas, but here is what I got to work. I created my own `CalendarService` class, which converts the dates from:

> 2010-10-13T18:30:00.000-05:00

to:

> 2010-10-13 18:30:00

These dates are then converted to the same (and correct) DateTime in any time zone.

```
internal class CalendarService2 : CalendarService
{
    public CalendarService2(string applicationName) : base(applicationName) { }

    public new EventFeed Query(EventQuery feedQuery)
    {
        EventFeed feed = new EventFeed(feedQuery.Uri, this);
        using (Stream input = base.Query(feedQuery.Uri, DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(input);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("(//@startTime|//@endTime)[contains(.,'.000-')]");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                node.Value = node.Value.Remove(node.Value.Length - 10).Replace('T', ' ');
            }
            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                doc.Save(output);
                output.Position = 0;
                feed.NewAtomEntry += new FeedParserEventHandler(this.OnParsedNewEntry);
                feed.NewExtensionElement += new ExtensionElementEventHandler(this.OnNewExtensionElement);
                feed.Parse(output, AlternativeFormat.Atom);
            }
        }
        return feed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't fight it.  The Google.GData.Calendar library sets each time to the system's local time.  [Here's what I could dig up about it](http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-dotnet-client-library/browse_thread/thread/b9f286a692c45df).

You'll need to convert all those times from every EventEntry

```
    DateTime offsetStartTime = GetTimeZoneOffset(entry.Times[0].StartTime, "Mountain Standard Time");

    public static DateTime GetTimeZoneOffset(DateTime dt, string win32Id)
    {
        var timeUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(win32Id);
        DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
        return cstTime;

    }
```